# Is $f(z) = e^{iz}$ is a bounded or unbounded function on $\Bbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

let  $f:\Bbb C→\Bbb C$ defined by

$f(z) = e^{iz}$.  where $\Bbb C$ is complex field

My question is whether $f(z) = e^{iz}$ is a bounded or unbounded function on C ?

My attempt : I take $f(z) = e^{iz}$

$f(x +iy) = \dfrac1{e^y}(\cos x +i\sin x)$  where $z = x+iy$

I know that sine and cosine is a bounded function,,,,,

Therfore $f(z) = e^{iz}$ is a bounded function on $\Bbb C$.

Is my answer is correct or not ? please verify it.

Comment: "I know that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are bounded" - but what about the $e^{-y}$?

Comment: ok,,,@ john Doe  but e^-y will be 0 when y tend to infinity and i know that 1/0 is infinity ,,,am i correct @ john doe

Comment: What happens when $y\to -\infty$?

Comment: ok ,,again it will become unbounded @ mark Viola...Am i right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is unbounded because, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $f(-ni)=e^n$.

Comment: thanks @ jose carlos santos..very nice and simple  counterexample ..i like it,,,

Answer (score 7):

$e^{iz}$ is unbounded on $\mathbb C$  as is every nonconstant entire function (by Liouville's Theorem).

In your statement, the factor $(\cos x + i\sin x)$ is indeed bounded (its absolute value is $1$), but the factor $1/e^{y}$ can be made arbitrarily large by taking $y$ to be a sufficiently large negative number.

Thus their product, which is $e^{iz}$, is unbounded.

Comment: thanks,,, @ MPW

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to argue that if $e^z$ is bounded, it obtains a global maximum at some point. That's not possible, since its differential considered as a function of $x$ and $y$ doesn't vanish .

Answer (score 0):

Your function is indeed unbounded, as most comments have told you. However, something important to keep in mind is that you have just shown that $e^{iz}$ is a bounded function when restricted to the upper open complex plane $\mathbb{C}_+= \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Im(z)>0 \}$. This can be useful sometimes.